# Let $S$ be the subset of $\{1, 2, \dots, 100\}$ where $|S|=26$. Then, $S$ contains an odd or there exists $x,y\in S$ such that $x|y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

If it contains an odd then we are done. Otherwise there will be $26$ even numbers which is $1$ more than the half of the total even numbers in the set. But I have no idea how to do it. Will Pigeonhole principle be helpful? Does smallest number in the set is the required $x$?

Comment: The answer to your last question is no: $\{48,50,52,54,\ldots, 90,92,94,98,100\}$ does not have $\min =48$ dividing any other element

Comment: Consider $y=2x$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Try proof by contradiction. It follows that $S$ contains only even numbers. Also, if $x$ is in $S$ then $2x$ can't be in $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $S$ does not contain an odd number. Notice that every even number in the set $\{1,2,\dots,100\}$ is of the form $2^ab$ where $a\geq1$ and $b$ is an odd integer between $1$ and $49$ ($25$ options). Because of this there must be two numbers with the same value of $b$ in $S$, that is $2^ab$ and $2^cb$, this is a contradiction as one would divide the other.